# Spring-Kafka "Could not obtain cluster info" when Observation is enabled

Tags: spring-kafka

Setup:
I'm using Spring boot 3.1.5 (spring-kafka 3.0.12).

Question/Issue:
When I enabled observation for my kafka consumer/producer I am seeing constant errors by the AdminClient attempting to get the clusterId.  I debugged the configs and the client is utilizing the same bootstrap servers as my consumer/producer. I assume that is correct but I'm not sure.

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Related questions:

1. Why does observation need the clusterId (for metrics grouping or ?) when my consumer/producer don't need it when observation is not?
2. How can I debug the reason for the timeout?  I cant seem to find any errors related to "connection refused", or anything related to failing connecting to the host.
3. I've seen issues in spring kafka posted like, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2505, but it is not clear to me if it's exactly related to my question or not (I'm not using spring cloud stream).

`2023-11-15 10:46:56.837 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1,traceId=,spanId=,userId=,yentaId=, uri=] ERROR 27551 [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.c.l.LogAccessor                      : Could not obtain cluster info`

`java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`
`at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1960)`
`at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2095)`
`at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:180)`
`at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.clusterId(KafkaAdmin.java:323)`
`at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.obtainClusterId(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:998)`
`at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.clusterId(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:991)`
`at org.springframework.kafka.support.micrometer.KafkaRecordReceiverContext.<init>(KafkaRecordReceiverContext.java:51)`
`at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.lambda$doInvokeRecordListener$56(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2768)`
`at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.createNotStarted(Observation.java:169)`
`at io.micrometer.observation.docs.ObservationDocumentation.observation(ObservationDocumentation.java:188)`
`at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2765)`
`at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2622)`
`at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2508)`
`....\`

Disabling observation makes the error go away but that isn't useful to me.  I debugged into the framework and as far as I can tell, KafkaAdmin/client are configured with the proper broker servers. I'm unsure if the clusterId retrieval requires zookeeper properties configured or not (maybe this request goes to ZK to get the cluster info).  I could not find any related properties regarding this in spring-kafka documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain the timeout but there is no direct connection to ZK by the kafka-clients for a long time now. Maybe your user doesn't have admin permissions?

As a work around (until you figure out the problem), you can inject a `KafkaAdmin` into the container(s) with a dummy `clusterId`.

```java
    /**
     * Set the cluster id. Use this to prevent attempting to fetch the cluster id
     * from the broker, perhaps if the user does not have admin permissions.
     * @param clusterId the clusterId to set
     * @since 3.1
     */
    public void setClusterId(String clusterId) {
        this.clusterId = clusterId;
    }
```

3.1 is scheduled to be released next week; with 3.0.x, you can subclass `KafkaAdmin` and override `clusterId()` to return a dummy id.

Alternatively, you can use a custom `KafkaListenerObservationConvention` with a `KafkaRecordReceiverContext` that does not attempt to retrieve the cluster id.

Comment: Yes that was my first thought -- hardcoding some dumby-id.  The reason I haven't yet is that I was not able to figure out what `clusterId` was used for. In the framework code, I saw it retrieving it but I could not find what it was actually `used` for.  So I was skeptical based on its importance.

As for user permissions -- does this clusterId retrieval require more permissions than my application has for kafka listener/template ?  Thanks for the fast response Gary, much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know anything about Kafka permissions, sorry. The clusterId is used as part of the `remoteServiceName` in the default `KafkaRecordReceiverContext` for observation.

Comment: I looked at creating custom ObservationConvention and ReceiverContext but when debugging, it doesn't appear the fmwk is handling the Receivercontext supplier generically.  It's hardcoded the context supplier as well as the clusterId supplier. 
```
Observation observation = KafkaListenerObservation.LISTENER_OBSERVATION.observation(
     this.containerProperties.getObservationConvention(),
     DefaultKafkaListenerObservationConvention.INSTANCE,
     () -> new KafkaRecordReceiverContext(cRecord, getListenerId(), this::clusterId),
     this.observationRegistry)```

Comment: Injecting my own KafkaAdmin using the container customizer works though, as u suggested